# How to handle linking to script and css files in a multiple page HTML/jquery only app

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Here's the idea - building an HTML5/jquery/jquerymobile/local storage based mobile/tablet app intended to be put through Phonegap or Nomad for purposes of native mobile device support.

This, in and of itself, isn't an issue and is essentially underway.  The app started out as a .net Razor/MVC but it looks like it will be going to HTML5 pages only for purposes of using Phonegap/Nomad, thus losing the ability for Layouts/Masterpages.

The question would be is there any way to handle masterpage type functionality with regard to linking to javascript and css resources so that if we change or update we don't have to manually update multiple files?  The app will probably be around 20 separate pages and I don't want to build one big HTML page with all the "pages" defined within it, that will get far too messy.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jeff welcome to SO(Stack Overflow). The good news is that since it is a phonegap app you only have to define the css or js files in the index page that your app will start with. The rest can be "page fragments". JQM will utilize ajax to load the other pages and will ignore the `<head>` section anyways. JQM just looks for `<div data-role="page">` and inserts that into the first page. So feel free to keep it simple and just have something like this:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Fragment</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>This page gets pulled into the first pages dom when you click on the link to it.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note that you wouldn't want to do this in a webapp because someone could hit refresh or could be arriving to that page via link or direct input. However i see no reason not to do it this way in phonegap since they can't hit refresh etc.**